# SQL Different column type comparison error

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, comparison

Hi I have a stored procedure which suppose to compare between 2 columns on different tables

1. Users.ID => int
2. Trans.ID => nvarchar

Sometimes the value in Trans.ID is not numeric at all, and sometimes it's null, which causes an error while trying to compare

is there a way to try to parse Trans.ID into a number and in case it doesn't succeed to return 0??

I tried `NullIf()` but it doesn't work when the value inside is not numeric.

Comment: which version of Database are you using?

Comment: mssql, thanks for quick ans :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
select * from users u 
inner join trans t on u.userid  = (CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(t.id) = 1 THEN CONVERT(int, t.id) ELSE 0 END)
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Trans.ID is a `varchar(20)` field, you can convert the `Users.ID` field to a varchar, use `COALESCE` to handle NULL values, and compare as follows:

```
WHERE CAST(Users.ID AS varchar(20)) = COALESCE(Trans.ID, '')
```

Answer (score 3):

If using sql server you can do this

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(Trans.ID) = 0  then null 
else cast(Trans.ID as int) end = Users.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is just equality comparison (which I think it is to make sense), I would convert `Users.ID` to `NVARCHAR` and then compare with `Trans.ID`.

Answer (score 0):

IsNumeric() is not always right, e.g. ' - ' and '.' both return 1 for IsNumeric, but will fail your query.

This function (Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4690444/573261))

```
create function dbo.GetNumeric(@x varchar(10)) returns float as
begin
return
    case
    when @x is null or @x = '' then null -- blanks
    when @x like '%[^0-9e.+-]%' then null -- non valid char found
    when @x like 'e%' or @x like '%e%[e.]%' then null -- e cannot be first, and cannot be followed by e/.
    when @x like '%e%_%[+-]%' then null -- nothing must come between e and +/-
    when @x='.' or @x like '%.%.%' then null -- no more than one decimal, and not the decimal alone
    when @x like '%[^e][+-]%' then null -- no more than one of either +/-, and it must be at the start
    when @x like '%[+-]%[+-]%' and not @x like '%[+-]%e[+-]%' then null
    else convert(float,@x)
    end
end
```

Your query (involving inequality)

```
where users.id >= case when IsNull(dbo.GetNumeric(trans.id),0)
```

And if trans.id does not involve decimal points

```
where user.id >= case when trans.id not like '%[^0-9]%' and trans.id >''
                      then trans.id end
```

Of course, if it's a simple equality, just cast the int to a varchar

```
where right(users.id,10) = trans.id
```